# Где здесь утечка памяти?

Tags: c++, c, qt, утечка-памяти, valgrind

QT
mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setWindowTitle("Test");
    mainWidget = new QWidget(this);
    mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    question = new QLabel("Hello world", mainWidget);
    mainWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);

    mainLayout->addWidget(question);

    setCentralWidget(mainWidget);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QWidget>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    QLabel *question;
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout;
    QWidget *mainWidget;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image: Вот что говорит Valgrind]

Самое простое приложение на свете. Вот что говорит Valgrind

Текстовый вывод Valgrind

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./untitled
==57961== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==57961== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==57961== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==57961== Command: ./untitled
==57961== 
==57961== 
==57961== HEAP SUMMARY:
==57961==     in use at exit: 340,060 bytes in 7,722 blocks
==57961==   total heap usage: 70,991 allocs, 63,269 frees, 82,974,658 bytes allocated
==57961== 
==57961== 288 (256 direct, 32 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 195 of 322
==57961==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==57961==    by 0x8E872F4: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.12.0)
==57961==    by 0x8E879B8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.12.0)
==57961==    by 0x8E88FDC: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.12.0)
==57961==    by 0x8E9006C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.12.0)
==57961==    by 0x94E09D9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.11)
==57961==    by 0x94E16AF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.11)
==57961==    by 0x94DEB82: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.11)
==57961==    by 0x94E004D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.11)
==57961==    by 0x94E3DBF: XML_ParseBuffer (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.11)
==57961==    by 0x8E8DF42: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.12.0)
==57961==    by 0x8E8E37B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.12.0)
==57961== 
==57961== LEAK SUMMARY:
==57961==    definitely lost: 256 bytes in 1 blocks
==57961==    indirectly lost: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==57961==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==57961==    still reachable: 339,772 bytes in 7,720 blocks
==57961==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==57961== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==57961== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==57961== 
==57961== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==57961== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: во-первых, почему вывод валгринда вы приводите изображением? Во-вторых скомпилируйте программу с -g флагом и запустите valgrind с флагом --leak-check=full

Comment: Это и есть то что вы хотите увидеть

Comment: Вы на QT давно программируете ? Вы понимаете, как QT памятью управляет? Они тут и не должны быть нужны

Comment: Больше скажу - утечка только после добавления QLabel. Если Qlabel не создаю - утечки нет

Comment: @АндрейПетров какой наивный? Вы сами не понимаете как в Qt освобождается память в виджетах и наивно говорите что раз Qt то delete не нужны. delete не нужен только в том случае, если выделенная память освобождается родителем объекта. А какой родитель у вашего mainLayout?

Comment: но, повоторюсь: скомпилируйте программу с -g и запустите valgring с --leak-check=full

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Тот вывод, который на скрине - и есть то что вы хотите увидеть. Программа уже скомпилированна с флагом -g и valgrind уже запущен с параметром --leak-check=full

Comment: @АндрейПетров значит это не весь вывод valgrind - и что это за привычка выводить текстовую инфу картинкой? Вам самому это удобно? А другим?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Ну вы же видите ERROR SUMMARY и HEAP SUMMARY
Начало и конец !

Comment: @АндрейПетров я ничего не вижу на вашей картинке - почитайте правила сообщества что они говорят по поводу изображений и почему

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Добавил текстовый вывод

Comment: а у вас процессор не amd случаем?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Неа, не amd, Intel. добавив delete mainLayout  - ничего не изменилось

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Так вот, да, самое комичное, что просто удалив строки содержащие QLable - утечка пропадает

Comment: @АндрейПетров я не говорил добавлять delete для mainLayout - я лишь спросил какой у него родитель? При его создании вы родителя не указали, что сразу бросается в глаза, конечно, setLyout устанавливает родителя, но это можно узнать только заглянув в документацию (чего вы по-видимому не сделали). Я к тому что нужно быть аккуратным с выделением памяти в QT - концепция используемая в QT на порядок хуже концепции умных указателей.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Проблема в том, что я это знаю и первое время игнорировал вашу просьбу добавить туда delete. Ровно так же, как и с компиляцией. В конечном итоге я сделал все, чтобы вы поверили мне, что ваши просьбы были удовлетворены, теперь удовлетворите мою - помогите)

Answer (score 1):

Я могу и ошибаться, так как в QT не работал, и знаю его очень поверхностно. Но, по мне, очевидно:

1. MainWindow _ родитель QMainWindow, а он в свою очередь является
   QWidget _ ом.
2. MainWindow имеет указатель `mainWidget` на свою копию (другой QWidget) и имеет
   еще один виджет:  `question = new QLabel("Hello world", mainWidget);`, который, по всей видимости, `размещается в mainWidget`.

Так вот: когда удаляется  `MainWindow w`, его родитель не может удалять этот самый question, так как он размещен в другом виджете.

Как исправить:

- Если классу нужен указатель на другой виджет(свою копию), то в
  деструкторе явно удалить эту копию `delete mainWidget`
- Или просто(не понимаю зачем классу его копия и еще другой, не принадлежащий ему, а этой копии) убрать этот самый указатель
  `QWidget *mainWidget` и исправить:

  question = new QLabel("Hello world");

Если гуру меня подправят, буду благодарен.
P.S. текстовый вывод Valgrind тут не нужен оказался....

Comment: Ну так родителем mainWidget является MainWindow. MainWindow вызывает деструктор mainWidget и затем деструктор mainWidget вызывает деструктор QLabel

Comment: Ну и методом проб - было установлено, что если добавить delete для QLable ситуация не поменяется

Comment: @Андрей Петров,еще раз, класс имеет указатель на дедушку, и его отец не может иметь никакого отношения с дедушкой другого дедушку. Это же все таки не виртуальный базовый класс.

Comment: ОКей, я согласен с вами, да, QLable надо чистить.Но та утечка, которую я показывал - она осталась. Т.е  QT Creator ее показывает и относит к External Errors.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте просто не держал указатель на свою копию. Эта копия если вам нужна, то его нужно удалять в деструкторе. Еще раз подумайте зачем виджету создать свою же копию и  еще другой виджет, который  размещен в этой копии. Виджет  самостоятельно не удалит свою копию, пока ему не дадут явную инструкцию в деструкторе

Answer (score 0):

QMainWidget имеет virtual деструктор. Так как он у Вас объявлен явно, то Вам следует сделать его тоже virtual. Возможно дело в этом.